# Why am I having toggle issues with a repeater?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, toggle

I have a repeater and there is a div and button inside it.
But as you know in repeater ids are changed. Like
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptToogle_**ctl00**_btnToogle
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptToogle_**ctl01**_btnToogle
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptToogle_**ctl02**_btnToogle

That code is working but it's working for all. I mean when I click every div is opening.
I just want to open I selected, not all of them. How can I fix it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[id*="btnToogle"]').click(function () {
            $('[id*="divToogle"]').slideToggle(100);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:Repeater id="rptToogle" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button id="btnToogle" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Button>
        <div id="divToogle" runat="server" style="display:none;">
             asdasd, asdasd, asdasd
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I modified my answer in-case you had seen it earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating multiple divs with the id="divToggle". Technically speaking you really shouldn't do this as it is invalid markup to have the different DOM elements with the same ids (although browsers will allow it).

You can select the current button by using $(this) and then you can leverage jquery's next() selector to get the div next to the button like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('[id*="btnToogle"]').click(function () {
            //select the very next sibling of this button, which we know is the div
            $(this).next().slideToggle(100);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please note, however, that using next() can be dangerous if you start editing your markup, because it is a relative selector, not absolute (it gets the next element, not a specific element by id).

Comment: It must be working but I guess it can't find next sibling. I removed id of div also. <div>fooo</div>

Comment: I guess i fix it, because i had a <br /> tag after button. Anyway when I click it's ok but second click it must be closed but not.

Answer (score 3):

Try this... use `$(this)` instead of `$('[id*="divToogle"]')` inside the `click`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[id*="btnToogle"]').click(function () {
            $(this).slideToggle(100);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot click on a hidden element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next` method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id*="btnToogle"]').click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle(100);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Exactly, id's are also unique. But after page renders it changes as you know. Because it's in repeater. Your code is not working.

Comment: @kad1r Yes, because I had suggested using classes. In your markup IDs are the same, this makes your document _invalid_, try the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

USE rptToogle_ItemBound method & modify you code as per example below

```
    protected void rptToogle_ItemBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
            int year = Convert.ToInt32(drv["Year"]);
            Panel pnl = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnlToggle");
        // Your code

        }
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ;
        }
    }


    <asp:Repeater id="rptToogle" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptToggle_ItemBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button id="btnToogle" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Button>
               <asp:Panel ID="pnlToggle" runat="server" Visible="false">

                 //Use Panel as this also need unique ID for your code to work properly
                </asp:Panel>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Modify Script, this will generate the unique button id & will initiate script for particular button event only

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= btnToogle.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            $("#<%= pnlToogle.ClientID %>").slideToggle(100);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```